# The "illegal character" in jquery appendTo()

Tags: jquery, appendto, illegal-characters

here is my jquery appendTo() code：

```
$('<li><a href="javascript:void (0)" onmousedown="document.getElementById('searchType_banner').value='p';">document</a></li>').appendTo('.wapper');
```

in firebug it remind me an error that "missing ) after argument list" in "onmousedown" position,and sometimes it remind me that "illegal character" error.But I don't think I miss any ")" .

So what should not appear in the appendTo() or which I should noticed in appendTo() .Why the error above happened,how can I solve this problem?

thank you

Comment: @hh , just few suggestions, i think you don't need href there , and why to make it so complicated with inline code, make it more cleaner.

Comment: @kobe,I think in a website ,different pages must have some same pages,like menu,logo.So I want use jquery to append the same part to the common container .header.it could save html code.furthermore,the website I'm doing is copy from anther,include the javascript ,so I copy it at all

Comment: @kobe: hh might need the `href` there for styling and at least it isn't `href="#"`. I agree with you about the `onmousedown` inside jQuery though.

Comment: @mu yeah i agree. the reason i mentioned is when you have too many inline styles or code, we endup doing these kind of mistakes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The selector is essentially a string, so you're breaking your string with the single quotes. You need to escape them.

`$('<li><a href="javascript:void (0)" onmousedown="document.getElementById(\'searchType_banner\').value=\"p\";">document</a></li>').appendTo('.wapper');`

Comment: @Robert Because, as seen here http://jsfiddle.net/zYWSv/2/ it doesn't work. It's not even close to valid HTML markup. A backslash inside an HTML attribute does not escape the closing delimiter for the attribute. Even your own fiddle's syntax highlighting shows you that your `onmousedown` attribute ends with the characters "(\". @kobe Please define 'work'.

Comment: @Phrogz: I suppose it's a good thing that my example was a jquery selector and not html... http://jsfiddle.net/FVrRJ/

Comment: @Robert What you have in that Fiddle is what I have in my answer, and not what you have above. You have correctly used escaped single-quotes in your example, not escaped double-quotes as seen in your answer above. Here is a (non-working) Fiddle based on your answer: http://jsfiddle.net/FVrRJ/1/

Comment: The answer I posted is not completely wrong and your hasty downvote is a bit aggravating for a quick typo that I didn't even notice until you were clear...

Comment: @Robert The moment you edit your answer to be correct I will happily remove my downvote. Until that point it is broken code that will only lead someone who doesn't know what they are doing further astray. I'm sorry that I did not make it clear from my comment what the problem was. I assumed that you would diff it with my answer and see your 'typo'.

Comment: @Phrogz , if it is a just typo error or very minor mistake you can correct the user or just update him before doing a downvote. If it isa blunder we can downvote otherwise , we should encourage.

Comment: @kobe You make a good point. If I had not already answered with correct code I would have happily fixed his typo. As it stood it was a duplicate, wrong answer. In general I'm very willing to edit questions and answers to fix formatting and grammar, but changing the substance of someone's answer—especially when that substance deals directly with the problem at hand—should be done with great caution.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the syntax highlighting on your own Stack Overflow question I think you can see what's going wrong. Notice where the string ends.

Here's how to fix it:

```
$('<li><a href="javascript:void (0)" onmousedown="document.getElementById(\'searchType_banner\').value=\'p\';">document</a></li>').appendTo('.wapper');
```

Alternative fix:

```
$('<li><a href="javascript:void (0)" onmousedown="document.getElementById(&quot;searchType_banner&quot;).value=&quot;p&quot;;">document</a></li>').appendTo('.wapper');
```

*Editorial: Ugh! You should not use anchor elements just for JavaScript. Use a `<button>` and style it like a link if you like. Here's how I'd write that:*

```
$('<button>document</button>').mousedown(function(){
  $('#searchType_banner').val('p');
}).appendTo('.wapper');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('<a></a>').html('document').mousedown(function(){}).wrap('<li></li>').appendTo('.wapper');
```